# how to redirect 404 to attachment.php?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, attachments

I have a problem, I have many url attachments with / amp, example:

```
siteweb.com/article-2019/image2/amp
siteweb.com/article-2019/image3/amp
siteweb.com/article-2019/image4/amp
```

all these give me 404 error
But the original url and where the images are are like this

```
siteweb.com/article-2019/image2/
siteweb.com/article-2019/image3/
siteweb.com/article-2019/image4/
```

Any way to do it with htacces?

Comment: `attachment.php` doesn't determine what gets shown, what gets shown determines the template, by the time WP tries to figure out which template to show, it's already fetched the posts. I'd suggest reporting this bug to the vendor that implements your Amp support ( and asking them to support attachment pages in Amp )

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller:

```
RewriteRule (.+/)amp$ /$1 [R,L]
```

This redirects a request for `/<something>/amp` to `/<something/` - removing the "amp" suffix.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect.